# How do I count the number of occurrences of values in 2 arrays (one is part of the other) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, count

So say I have an array `A = [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,7]`

This is part of another larger array `B = [1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7]`

What I'd like to do is to count how many times each element appears in `A`, and divide it by the times it appears in `B`, and hopefully tabulate the result using the `tabulate` function.

I'd like my final tabulated result to look as follows

```
Element - Occurrence - %age of occurrence
1   -   1    -    100%
2   -   2    -    50%   
3   -   1    -    33.3%
4   -   1    -    100%
5   -   3    -    100%
6   -   0    -    0%
7   -   1    -    100%
```

I believe this would involve  a for loop where I create a new array `C` such that it identifies which elements in `A` appear in `B` and each time it does add `1` to its respective value, and if it doesn't exist in `B`, return `0`. I don't know how to proceed though and some direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Something something `accumarray`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good use case for `hist`, which is usually quite fast. You can bin the data in `A` to histogram bins ranging from `min(A)` to `max(A)`, and apply the same bins to allocate the data in `B`. Then you can get your percentage values by simply dividing the numbers of occurrences in both arrays.

For example:

```
[nA, uA] = hist(A, min(A):max(A));
nB = hist(B, uA);
result = 100*(nA./nB)'
```

Edit: the numbers of occurrences of elements of `A` is given by `nA`.

Comment: Or maybe `uA = unique(A);` (depending on what the OP wants)

Comment: @LuisMendo Indeed. Judging by the appearance of the line `6   -   0    -    0%` the OP does want to include values not in A, too.

Comment: True! I hadn't noticed that

Comment: Hi @mikkola, thanks for the answer! Your bit of code worked perfectly to give me the percentage values. However I would like to include the second column I mentioned as well, i.e, the number of occurrences of A in B. Or maybe even just the occurrences of A. However please note that it should say that there are zero occurrences for 6 (in this case). Otherwise, the array lengths do not match and I can't append them the way I'd like.

Comment: @rahulk92 The occurrence counts corresponding to your second column are given by `nA`. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @LuisMendo Hi, thanks for the reply, I did use the unique function in order to get the length of my array since it was significantly large. However I don't think I can use it here as mikkola has stated.

Comment: @mikkola Ahhh yes of course, that makes sense. I didn't try thinking over the code before pasting and replacing it with my values, sorry! But I have the result exactly as I wanted it now, thank you!